# How to get date using timezone saved in options?

Tags: date, date-time, timezones

This code does not work correctly and returns time using timezone from computer and ignoring timezone stored in WordPress options:

```
date_default_timezone_set( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) );
$hours = date( 'H', strtotime( $timestamp ) );
date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());
```

WordPress saves timezone in options section but 'timezone_string' option in wp_options table is empty. Also the code generates warnings.

**How to get date using timezone saved in options correctly?**

**Where does WordPress store an Timezone which can be edited in options section?**

Comment: You should use `current_time('mysql')` to get the current date based on wordpress timezone settings. The return value would be `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` formatted time. This is used to get the time, not the timezone name or GMT difference.

Comment: @Shazzad Where does WordPress store an Timezone which can be edited in options section?

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

`$mytheme_timezone = get_option('timezone_string');
date_default_timezone_set($mytheme_timezone);`

in my themes functions.php. For me this has worked without any warnings.

I've also tested whether my script is in different timezone than php.ini:

```
 if (strcmp($mytheme_timezone, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
 echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
}
else {
 echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
}
```

Please improve this answer if you have more insight.